# Unable to enter into a particular switch case

Tags: c, stm32

The first case of switch is to initialize the values, when i enter into the function the switch is not going to case INI_QUEUE, instead its going to CHECK_QUEUE or ENABLE_QUEUE.
below is my code and debug snippet.

can anyone please tell me, what is the problem which is making it not to go to INI_QUEUE

```
main.c file
    int main(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
        char buffer[2] = { 0 };
      /* USER CODE END 1 */
    
      /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
    
      /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
      HAL_Init();
    
      /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
    
      /* USER CODE END Init */
    
      /* Configure the system clock */
      SystemClock_Config();
    
      /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
    
      /* USER CODE END SysInit */
    
      /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_USART2_UART_Init();
      MX_TIM14_Init();
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
     // HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim14);
      __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2,UART_IT_RXNE);
      // HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) buffer, 1);
      /* USER CODE END 2 */
    
      /* Infinite loop */
      /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    
      while (1)
      {
        //  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) buffer, 1);
          fn_cirQ();
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    
        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    
      }
      /* USER CODE END 3 */
    }

    typedef enum{
        INI_QUEUE, CHECK_COM, EN_QUEUE, DE_QUEUE, UART_SEND
    }Qstate;
    void init_queue(queues *q, int max_size){
          q->size =max_size;
          q->values = malloc(sizeof(int)*q->size);
          q->num = 0;
          q->front = 0;
          q->rare = 0;
      }
    void fn_cirQ()
    {
        queues q1;
        static Qstate queuestates = INI_QUEUE;
        switch (queuestates)
        {
        case INI_QUEUE:
            init_queue(&q1, SIZE);
            queuestates = CHECK_COM;
        break;
        case CHECK_COM:
            if(Q_state == 0xFF)
            {
                queuestates = EN_QUEUE;
            }
            else if(Q_state == 0x00)
            {
                queuestates = DE_QUEUE;
            }
            else if(Q_state != 0x55)
            {
                HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) errormsg, 20);
            }
        break;
        case EN_QUEUE:
            en_queue(&q1, temp[1]);
            Q_state = 0x55;
            j = 0;
            queuestates = UART_SEND;
        break;
        case DE_QUEUE:
            dequeue(&q1);
            Q_state = 0x55;
            j=0;
            queuestates = UART_SEND;
        break;
        case UART_SEND:
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)&q1, sizeof(q1));
            queuestates = CHECK_COM;
        break;
    }
    }
```

[debug window,queuestates is assigned with CHECK_COM state instead of INI_QUEUE]

Comment: Code appears to be fine. If possible keep `conditional break point` on `queuestates` check if any write happens before the function call.  
There can be multiple reasons where inadvertently `queuestates` is overwritten. for  example array out of bound access, wrong pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Try to set optimization level to none (-O0) and check this behaviour again.

Answer (score 3):

The initialization of a static variable is only done once, at program start-up. So the first time the function is called, it will go to the `INI_QUEUE` case.

From there on, any next time the function is called it will go the queue state set by the previous call.

But the first time it *will* go to `INI_QUEUE`.

Comment: I am taking input from uart, in interrupt mode and after that i am calling function, in 1st iteration only it is declared as CHECK_SUM, as i showed in snippet above.

Comment: The only other possibility is that before `fn_cirQ` is called, a bug overwrote `queuestates`. Although the variable is declared in the function, it is still stored in the global data segment, together with other global/static variables.